# Button not being positioned in React Native

Tags: react-native

My button seems to be not positioned in my react native project. The code that I have looks like this:

```
<Button style = "centered"
      onPress = {() => {Alert.alert('Button tapped!');} }
      title = "Confirm"
    />
```

Then in my style sheet I did this :

```
 centered:{
    position: 'absolute',
    top : 350,
}
```

And it did not work. Some other things that I tried:

```
style = {centered}
```

Gives a run-time error saying can not find variable centered

```
class = "centered"
```

Does not do anything, either.

According to suggestion, I tried creating a separate View for my button alone, but it gave an error saying JSX expressions must have one parent element. The code I tried:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>Select a time to be notified : </Text>
    <Picker
      style={styles.picker} itemStyle={styles.pickerItem}
      selectedValue={this.state.time}
      onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.setState({time: itemValue})}
    >
    <Picker.Item label="Now" value="now" />
      <Picker.Item label="After 1 minute" value="1min" />
      <Picker.Item label="After 5 minutes" value="5min" />
      <Picker.Item label="Custom time" value="ctime" />
    </Picker>
  </View>
  <View>
    <Button style = {{marginTop:350}}
    onPress = {() => {Alert.alert('Button tapped!');} }
    title = "Confirm"
    />
  </View>
);
```

Style sheet:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({


 container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  picker :{
    width: 200,
    height: 44,
    backgroundColor: '#CCE6FF',
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },

  pickerItem :{
    width: 200,
    height: 88,
    backgroundColor: '#CCE6FF',
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },

  notificationButton :{
    position: 'absolute',
    top : 50,
  },
});
```

Comment: You have to do this to add styling, you can just do `centered`. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html

Comment: @WilomGfx I don't know which part you are referring to, but I did do the part where I create a stylesheet. I also tried `style = {[styles.centered]}`, and it did not work, either

Comment: you need to do something like `style={{ marginTop: 34, color: 'blue'}}`

Comment: @JuniusL. I tried that too. So what I have right now is `      <Button style = {{marginTop:350}}`... Still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the button in a `View`, and style that view to center the button using `alignItems` and `justifyContent`.

```
<View>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>Select a time to be notified : </Text>
    <Picker
      style={styles.picker}
      itemStyle={styles.pickerItem}
      selectedValue={this.state.time}
      onValueChange={itemValue => this.setState({ time: itemValue })}>
      <Picker.Item label="Now" value="now" />
      <Picker.Item label="After 1 minute" value="1min" />
      <Picker.Item label="After 5 minutes" value="5min" />
      <Picker.Item label="Custom time" value="ctime" />
    </Picker>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.confirmButton}>
    <Button
      style={{ marginTop: 350 }}
      onPress={() => {
        Alert.alert('Button tapped!');
      }}
      title="Confirm"
    />
  </View>
</View>
```

Button Container style

```
confirmButton: {
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  marginTop: 10,
}
```

Comment: The button I'm trying to style is already in a View, and when I tried creating another View it gave another compile error, I suppose we can only have one View element in the whole thing?

Comment: "JSX expressions must have one parent element", at the line where I close the parenthesis for my return

Comment: Done. It is attached at the end

Comment: add the style in the view

Comment: Done also. I tried commenting out the justifyContent and the alignItems too, and all it did was moving everything to the top-left, and I still couldn't move my button freely

Comment: The stylesheet including information about the View is also attached in the question. I changed the class name to notificationButton for styling purposes

Comment: see my updated answer, if you have two elements in a return statement, wrap them in a view, that's why it was giving you that error.

Answer (score 1):

You need change the properties:

```
<Button style ={styles.centered}
      onPress = {() => {Alert.alert('Button tapped!');} }
      title = "Confirm"
    />
```

and the style:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  centered:{
  position: 'absolute',
  top : 350,
  }
})
```

Comment: I did everything except changing the `{[styles.centered]}` to `{{styles.centered}}`. So far it still doesn't work. When I changed it to curly braces, it gave an compile error saying comma expected. I have no idea what's going on anymore ;-;

Comment: Sorry my mistake, its need to be {styles.centered} i edit the answer

Comment: Thanks! My question has already been resolved, but still appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to center your button in the screen, wrap it in a `View` as specified by [Junius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3858806/junius-l).

Looking at your edited question, with code attached. You can return only one element from `render` method. So you need to wrap those 2 `View`s in a single parent `View`